# How to add only the content inside the selected folder to the jar

Tags: java, jar

So I have this java program which generates a jar file when we give the path to the content. But the problem is it generate more directories inside the jar file. For an example assume the relevant content is in the directory `/home/user/Desktop/sample/bin/tmp`. And when I create the jar file it has all those directories inside it, which means inside home directory there is `user` directory and inside it, there is `Desktop` directory and so on until the content inside the `tmp` folder is added. But what I want is, add the content inside this `tmp` folder directly to the jar without adding those extra directories. Here is the code which I used and I want to modify this or completely rewrite this. Any idea to do it...?

```java
    private static void createJar(File source, JarOutputStream target) throws IOException
        {
            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            try
            {
                if (source.isDirectory())
                {
                    String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
                    if (!name.isEmpty())
                    {
                        if (!name.endsWith("/"))
                            name += "/";
                        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                        entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                        target.putNextEntry(entry);
                        target.closeEntry();
                    }
                    for (File nestedFile: source.listFiles())
                        createJar(nestedFile, target);
                    return;
                }

                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(source.getPath().replace("\\", "/"));
                entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                target.putNextEntry(entry);
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (true)
                {
                    int count = in.read(buffer);
                    if (count == -1)
                        break;
                    target.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                target.closeEntry();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (in != null)
                    in.close();
            }
        }
```

Note that `source` is the directory and the `target` is the jar file that I'm going to create.

Comment: Remove everything except the for loop inside the if block.

Comment: @JBNizet then the output jar becomes null and there is no any file in there.

Comment: Then it means that your add() method (that you did't post) doesn't do what it should do, or that the directory is empty.

Comment: @JBNizet Oh my bad. That add method should be renamed to createJar. I just copy-paste the code but forgot to rename that method call. Sorry for the mistake, and the result is the same.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. You're using the whole path of every directory as entry name. You need to use the path that is after the root directory. I.e. if the directory is /home/user/Desktop/sample/bin/tmp/foo/bar, then the entry name should be /foo/bar/, not /home/user/Desktop/sample/bin/tmp/foo/bar/. So your recursive call must pass a third argument, which is the prefix to remove.

Comment: Yeah, That what I want to do. But the problem is the path is taken from another program and it gives the whole path. And that path is unpredictable, which means the depth of the path is unknown. So now how should I proceed?

Comment: That doesn't matter. You know the path. So you remove that path from the directory path. If the path you receive is /foo/bar, and it contains the directories /foo/bar/hello and /foo/bar/hello/world, then /foo/bar/hello must be added with the name hello/, and /foo/bar/hello/world must be added with the name hello/world/. All you need is to take the directory path, and remove the beginning. And you know what the beginning is: it's the path that you initially receive as argument.

Comment: To be honest I can't understand what you are saying. Can you give me an example of calling the method.

Comment: You really need to understand this. You want to put everything under /foo/bar/ into a jar. So the base directory for your jar is /foo/bar/, right? Currently, when you visit the directory /foo/bar/hello/world in your method, the entry you add to the jar is named "/foo/bar/hello/world/". What you need to name it, instead, is "hello/world/". So, how to do that? It's quite simple: you need to only take what comes after the base directory in the complete path. So, you take the full path "/foo/bar/hello/world/", and you remove the prefix "/foo/bar/". And what is left is the name you want.

Comment: OK, I've got what you said, But my problem is how to do it?

Comment: Path.relativize can help if you use Path rather, or in addition to File. Or you can just use Strings and use substring().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Hope someone would need it as I did.

```
 private static void createJar(File source, JarOutputStream target) {
        createJar(source, source, target);
    }



 private static void createJar(File source, File baseDir, JarOutputStream target) {
        BufferedInputStream in = null;

        try {
            if (!source.exists()){
                throw new IOException("Source directory is empty");
            }
            if (source.isDirectory()) {
                // For Jar entries, all path separates should be '/'(OS independent)
                String name = source.getPath().replace("\\", "/");
                if (!name.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!name.endsWith("/")) {
                        name += "/";
                    }
                    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(name);
                    entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
                    target.putNextEntry(entry);
                    target.closeEntry();
                }
                for (File nestedFile : source.listFiles()) {
                    createJar(nestedFile, baseDir, target);
                }
                return;
            }

            String entryName = baseDir.toPath().relativize(source.toPath()).toFile().getPath().replace("\\", "/");
            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(entryName);
            entry.setTime(source.lastModified());
            target.putNextEntry(entry);
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                int count = in.read(buffer);
                if (count == -1)
                    break;
                target.write(buffer, 0, count);
            }
            target.closeEntry();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(ignored);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```